# How to connect to pgadmin after fresh install

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

When I try to connect to pgadmin with username 'postgres' and no password, it says:

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the proper settings in pg_hba.conf?

See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postgresql.html how to do it.

What does your pg_hba.conf look like?

Comment: I just changed `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = 'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

change peer to trust in string or just add first line:
local   all             postgres                                     trust
as stated in [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)
then run pg_ctl reload